OrphanRemoval doesn't work and deleted associations remains in DB
Study.java :
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Study.All", attributeNodes = { 
@NamedAttributeNode("studyCenterList"),
...
public class Study {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "study", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<StudyCenter> studyCenterList;

...
}

StudyCenter.java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Center center;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Study study;

Despite having orphanRemoval = true, when I delete a Study I get
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`studies`.`study_center`, CONSTRAINT `FK2hmmh3c0w1tk8npi76hpvf09i` FOREIGN KEY (`study_id`) REFERENCES `study` (`id`))

Also when I update a study and add/remove studyCenters from it, added ones are inserted in the MySQL table but removed ones are still in the table.
Also if I have @JoinColumn in Study.java the constraint exception is gone but the study_center entry remains in the DB with NULL as study_id.
Please help me.

So the problem was that in the child, the parent is fetch eagerly. And Hibernate is too stupid to deal with it.
See Spring Data JPA : Repository DeleteById method not working
So
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Study study;

And deal with the "could not initialize proxy" errors with @Transactionnal.
